# How to validate user input is current date and time?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, extjs, ext.net

In html i use ext.net datefield

```
 <ext:DateField runat="server"  ID = "date"  Format="Y-m-d hh:mm:ss" SubmitFormat="Y-m-d H:i:s"  MarginSpec="0 0 0 60" FieldLabel="Gate In Date/Time" AllowBlank="false" IndicatorText="*" IndicatorCls="red-text"/>
```

when it view it shows correct date but the time is always 12:00:00.In javascript
i do it like this

```
var iframeID = $('iframe').attr('id');

var myDate = lazyMethod_get(iframeID, "formdetail", "date")
var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);


alert(myDate);
alert(today);

if (myDate > today) {
    alert("Entered date is greater than today's date ");
}
else {
    alert("Entered date is less than today's date ");
}}
```

the validation always alert the date entered less than today date. I just want to validate the date and time if the user insert for example 2016-02-03 the date is wrong and get current date.

Thank you.

Comment: The format string 'Y-m-d hh:mm:ss' and `toISOString()` won't produce the same result and therefore you can't do a simple `>`/`<` string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Time in microseconds.

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}
```

Do your formatting after you do your calculations.

What is your lazyMethod_get() workings.  Is it returning a string, or a Date object.

Comment: lazyMethod_get returns a string

Comment: you are then trying to compare a string with a date object.  you might need to `var date=Date(string)` depending on the format of the string.  You need to compare two date objects, which is why its easier to do the compare in microseconds, and then convert the output to a string for display.

Comment: `var minutes = 1000 * 60;
var hours = minutes * 60;
var days = hours * 24;
var years = days * 365;
var d = new Date();
var t = d.getTime();

var y = Math.round(t / years); y = 46`

Comment: You're out by a factor of 3. [*Date.now*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.now) returns milliseconds, not microseconds. ;-)

Comment: Fair call :-) my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

[*toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) generates a UTC date (i.e. the time zone offset is 00:00) so it may be a different date from the host system.

E.g. for a user in time zone +10:00 when it is 09:30 on 25 May, the above will return a date string for 24 May. Similarly, for systems where the offset is west of Greenwich, dates will be one day later for times in the evening (e.g. 20:30 on 25 May in time zone -04:00 will be 00:30 on 26 May UTC).

Answer (score 0):

First - The Ext.NET DateField only returns a date (MM-dd-yyyy) not a time.  The time always defaults to 12:00:00.

I would compare the year, day, and month of each.

javascript:

```
    var isToday = function (field) {
        var fieldDate = field.getValue();
        var today = new Date()


        if ((today.getFullYear() + today.getMonth() + today.getDate())
            == (fieldDate.getFullYear() + fieldDate.getMonth() + fieldDate.getDate())) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Markup:

```
    <ext:DateField ID="DateField1" runat="server">
        <Listeners>
            <Select Handler="alert( isToday(#{DateField1}) )" />
        </Listeners>
    </ext:DateField>
```